# Can't open menu in apps without a menu button or physical key

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, menu, softkey

My device doesn't have a physical menu button, and the app that I'm using doesn't have one of the menu buttons that users can click (the three dots).  How can I open the app's menu without a menu button or key?

Answer (score 3):

On most devices with softkeys for home/back/task-switcher, long-pressing the task switch button (right-most button, see below) will simulate pressing the menu button.

[image]

Comment: On Samsung Galaxy S7 that works as activating "split screen" for the current opened app. Any idea how to make that button act as menu button by long-pressing it?